# The new version of qgis (2.18.20) no longer scales maps in the print composer

Tags: qgis, qgis-2.18

I've used various versions of qgis to make maps and never had a problem scaling them until now.

My system updated, including my version of qgis which has the scale option but doesn't apply it to the map when clicked on.

Any suggestions, or is this a glitch in the software??

Comment: Could you describe more exactly, what you mean by "scaling the map"?

Comment: I'd like to scale the map, so say 1:25 000, or 1:500.  QGIS used to allow this but the new version doesn't, even though it has the scales which you can pick.

Comment: Can't you change the map scale from the map object properties like [so](https://imgur.com/a/7SoPD9Z)?

Comment: QGis still allows to set a scale for the map element, it did all the time through 2.18 and now 3.4.

Answer (score 3):

QGIS 2.18 does allow you to change the map scale in the print composer. Simply go to item properties and type in a new value in "Scale" box. You may have to click the "update preview" button to see the change.

[image]

This screenshot is from version 3.4, but it worked the same in 2.18.

Please note: 2.18.20 is not "the new version of QGIS." It's not even the latest sub-version of the old long-term release (LTR); the latest sub-version of the *old* LTR (2.18) is 2.18.27. The current LTR is 3.4.3.